# Server side changes in Angular html5 mode

Tags: html, angularjs

I was wondering if any one can tell me what are the server side changes which needs to be done when you change your mode in to html5 in Angular js. because  When I did tried to change the it to html 5 mode I was unable to go in to my inner html pages. in Angular API it says that  suers need to do a server side changes as well.

1. what are the server side changes
2. do we need to do any other changes as well ?

Comment: I haven't done this myself yet, but I believe that you need to rewrite your URLs so they point to your index.html (ie. the server will output `/index.html` when you request something like `/contact/london-office`). If you're using apache, look into `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish two type of calls:

1. HTML calls from the browser. These should be all remapped to serve your index or whatever.
2. JSON API requests. These should pass through to your app server.

How to distinguish between these two types of calls, and how to remap the former, depends strongly on your setup.

If you are using nginx, for instance, a combination of checking $http_accept to be `application/json` (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests and http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24http_HEADER) and rewrite (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite)  you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your server to rewrite everything to index.html per: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode ...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app

    DocumentRoot /path/to/app

    <Directory /path/to/app>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My app has params passed to a controller (via ui-router) so before html5mode I would goto 
www.blah.com/angapp/#/myUIrouterController?param_x=1&param_y=2 
Guessing browsers know that /#/ folder path part should serve index.html.

Now that # would be gone with html5mode, the server by default doesn't know to serve the index.html for that folder since the url will just be:
www.blah.com/angapp/myUIrouterController?param_x=1&param_y=2
myUIRouterController isn't a real file so the server would just serve a 404, Hence why I think the rewrites are needed so it knows to send everything to index.html (so above in combo with the <base> tag should work... note: requireBase is optional but heard it helps older browsers like IE9 maybe).